# Line-break after \not

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, relation-symbols

Why does `\not{=}` allow a line-break before the `=`?  Note that `\not=` does not allow a break.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\vbox{\hsize=0pt\relax $a\not{=}b$}
\vbox{\hsize=0pt\relax $a\not=b$}
\end{document}
```

(I had the misconception that `\not` is a macro that takes an argument, but in fact `\not=\mathchar"3236`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you typeset `$a\not{=}b$`, you can see

[image]

Knuth optimization: `\not` is a math relation symbol of width zero, but the glyph extends outside the bounding box, so to be placed in the middle of the following relation (no space is added between consecutive Rel atoms).

However `{=}` is not a Rel atom, but an Ord one.

So you get `\not`, thickmuskip, `=`. And a break is allowed.

See Heiko Oberdiek’s `centernot` package to see what it does to overcome the problem when the following symbol is not as wide as an equals sign.

The preferred input is actually `\neq` or `\ne`, which has the same outcome and could even give a better result with some fonts.

Comment: Or, with the `stackengine` package, `$a\mathrel{\stackengine{0pt}{=}{/}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}b$` will also work if `=` is substituted with something of different width.

Comment: you might mention that while with the input `\not=` you *do* get the expected output, using `\neq` which looks identical (with cm fonts) is generally preferable.

Comment: Thanks.  I know and use `\neq`; I noticed the line-break in trying to use `\not{D}` for the slashed notation.  Now I've done the right thing by loading the `slashed` package and using `\slashed{D}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\mathord
.\fam1 a
\mathrel
.\fam2 6
\mathord
.\mathrel
..\fam0 =
\mathord
.\fam1 b
```

It is like `\not{}` so you get a mathrel not which allows breaking, followed by `{=}` which is a mathord =